# My app rejected because uses the "prefs:root=" non-public URL scheme

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, app-store-connect, ios10, appstore-approval

I am got the message below from apple :

Your app uses the "prefs:root=" non-public URL scheme, which is a private entity. The use of non-public APIs is not permitted on the App Store because it can lead to a poor user experience should these APIs change.

app-prefs:root=privacy&path=location

Continuing to use or conceal non-public APIs in future submissions of this app may result in the termination of your Apple Developer account, as well as removal of all associated apps from the App Store.

Next Steps

To resolve this issue, please revise your app to provide the associated functionality using public APIs or remove the functionality using the "prefs:root" or "App-Prefs:root" URL scheme.

I am using below :

"App-Prefs:root=Privacy&path=LOCATION"

Kindly anyone can know how to solve this ?

Comment: The message is pretty clear, what is your question?

Comment: Hi @Sulthan the question is how can i solve this ?

Comment: @KhalidA. By not using a non-public url scheme?

Comment: @KhalidA. you have used this non-public url schemes for checking location service. right ?

Comment: Use `UIApplication.openSettingsURLString` to open settings app, you cannot do anything more specific.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apple's message is pretty clear. There is only one legal way to open Settings, and that is to use `UIApplication.openSettingsURLString`.

Answer (score -1):

**Solution is:** you have to remove `prefs:root` non-public url scheme and you can give alert message to user for location enable.

see below code for example :-

```
alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"GPS NOT AVAILABLE"  message:@"1. Go to Settings > Privacy > Location Services. \n 2. Make sure that Location Services is on." preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction *okay = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Okay" style: UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
        alert = nil;
    }];
    [alert addAction:okay];
    [alertVC presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:^{
        alert = nil;
    }];
```

i have removed non-public url scheme which is redirect to settings or location directly. after applied these changes apple approved my app.